# Htaccess url redirect only https urls

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to change all the https (only https urls, not http urls) url like below:

1) `https://www.domain.com/login` means `https://www.domain.com/index.php?_route_=login`

2) `https://www.domain.com/account` means `https://www.domain.com/index.php?_route_=login`

3) `https://www.domain.com/aboutus` means `https://www.domain.com/index.php?_route_=aboutus`

How do I achieve this..?
I am not very familiar with .htaccess.

Please help me.

Comment: [This](http://htaccess-guide.com/) will help you to get familiar with .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?_route_=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Once I add this code in live site, I am getting 403 forbidden error.
Please assist me